# Promedio ponderado de 2 notas en C#

Tags: c#

Tengo el siguiente código:

```
float A = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
float B = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

float totality = (A * 3.5f) + (B * 7.5f);
Console.WriteLine("MEDIA = " + $"{totality:0.00000}");
```

El problema está en que no da el resultado esperado (este ejercicio va con promedio ponderado)

Si ponemos (**A** = 5.0) y (**B** = 7.1) el resultado esperado es: 6.43182

Pero da = 70.7500

Agradezco sus respuestas!

Comment: esa cuenta da 70.75... no se como esperas que de 6.. a menos que a esa ecuacion le falten cosas! porque esa cuenta, no es la media de nada...

Comment: @gbianchi Si te fijas multiplicamos los valores por el peso de la nota (3.5 y 7.5) al multiplicarla por el peso de la nota debe dar el resultado esperado. Pero no se por que a mi no me da, quizás tenga algo mal, por ello necesito sus ayudas

Comment: no. 5 * 3.5 da 17.5.. 7.1 * 7.5 da 53.25 que sumados dan 70.75... no se como esperas ese resultado esperado

Answer (score 4, accepted):

De acuerdo a la ecuación que pones:

```
(A * X)+(A * Z) 

donde: A = 5, B = 7.1, X = 3.5, Z = 7.5

(5 x 3.5) + (7.1 x 7.5)

17.5+53.25

70.75
```

Para sacar la media ponderada, es necesario dividir entre la sumatoria de los pesos, es decir, tu formula tendria que quedar de la siguiente manera

```
((A * X)+(A * Z))/(X+Z)
```

Lo que se traduciría en

```
((5 x 3.5) + (7.1 x 7.5))/(3.5 + 7.5)
```

De esta manera el resultado sí es `6.4318`

En código deberías poner algo así tu formula:

```
float totality = ((A * 3.5f) + (B * 7.5f))/(3.5 + 7.5);
```

De esta manera, el resultado si sería el que esperas.

Espero haberte ayudado, saludos.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias amigo, justo lo que necesitaba!